# Nested loop called with shortcode duplicating the content above the main loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, shortcode

I'm trying to use a shortcode to call one post from a custom post type and display it inside another page's content. (Basically, we have a custom post type called 'testimonials' and we want to display a random testimonial on each page, but inside the page's content.) I used [this tutorial](http://digwp.com/2010/01/custom-query-shortcode/) as my starting point.

Here's my code:

```
function cd_random_testimonial($atts) {

   // EXAMPLE USAGE:
   //[loop the_query="showposts=1&post_type=testimonials&orderby=rand"]

   // Defaults
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  "the_query" => ''
   ), $atts));

   // de-funkify query
   $the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
   $the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

   // query is made  
   query_posts($the_query);

   // Reset and setup variables
   $output = '';

   // the loop
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      $testimonial = the_content($post->ID);
      $clientname = get_the_title($post->ID); 

      // output all findings - CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR LIKING
      $output .= '<blockquote><p class="quote">';
      $output .= get_the_content($post->ID);
      $output .= '</p><p class="right">~ ';
      $output .= $clientname;
      $output .= '</p></blockquote>';

   endwhile; else:

      $output .= 'nothing found.';

   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   return $output;

    }
    add_shortcode("loop", "cd_random_testimonial");
```

It's working exactly as it should where the shortcode is entered, but it's also adding that same content above the page's content.

How do I keep it from posting that extra content and just stay where it's supposed to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few errors in your code. Below you can see how it should look like:

```
function cd_random_testimonial($atts) {

    // EXAMPLE USAGE:
    // [loop the_query="showposts=1&post_type=testimonials&orderby=rand"]

    // Defaults
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'the_query' => ''
        ), $atts));

    // de-funkify query
    $the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
    $the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

    // query is made
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $the_query );  // use custom WP_Query instead of query_posts

    // Reset and setup variables
    $output = '';

    // the loop
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();

            // the_content outputs content and you want to return it; and it doesn't take post_id as argument... and you don't use this variable, so you can delete this line, I guess
            // $testimonial = get_the_content();  
            $clientname = get_the_title(); // it doesn't take post_id as argument

            // output all findings - CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR LIKING
            $output .= '<blockquote><p class="quote">';
            $output .= get_the_content();  // doesn't take argument
            $output .= '</p><p class="right">~ ';
            $output .= $clientname;
            $output .= '</p></blockquote>';
        }
    } else {
        $output = 'nothing found.';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("loop", "cd_random_testimonial");
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks. This is what happens when you try to hack a three-year-old tutorial. :)